# Big Query and Google Analytics UI do not match when ecommerce action filter applied

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

We are validating a query in Big Query, and cannot get the results to match with the google analytics UI. A similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785211/google-analytics-user-count-not-matching-big-query-user-count), but in our case the the mismatch only occurs when we apply a specific filter on ecommerce_action.action_type.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct fullVisitorId+cast(visitid as string)) AS sessions
FROM (
  SELECT
    device.browserVersion,
    geoNetwork.networkLocation,
    geoNetwork.networkDomain,
    geoNetwork.city,
    geoNetwork.country,
    geoNetwork.continent,
    geoNetwork.region,
    device.browserSize,
    visitNumber,
    trafficSource.source,
    trafficSource.medium,
    fullvisitorId,
    visitId,
    device.screenResolution,
    device.flashVersion,
    device.operatingSystem,
    device.browser,
    totals.pageviews,
    channelGrouping,
    totals.transactionRevenue,
    totals.timeOnSite,
    totals.newVisits,
    totals.visits,
    date,
    hits.eCommerceAction.action_type
  FROM
    (select * 
     from TABLE_DATE_RANGE([zzzzzzzzz.ga_sessions_], 
    <range>) ))t
WHERE
 hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '2' and <stuff to remove bots>
  )
```

From the UI using the built in shopping behavior report, we get 3.836M unique sessions with a product detail view, compared with 3.684M unique sessions in Big Query using the query above.

A few questions:
1) We are under the impression the shopping behavior report "Sessions with Product View" breakdown is based off of the ecommerce_action.actiontype filter. Is that true?
2) Is there a .totals pre-aggregated table that the UI maybe pulling from?

Comment: Be aware that `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` is approximate when using legacy SQL. Either use standard SQL instead (preferred) or use `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT` with legacy SQL.

Comment: Yes we found that EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT gets us within 0.3% after being pointed to it in #measure. Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: Also be careful on retrieving columns you won't be using, this will make your queries more expensive. And I recommend following Elliott's suggestion, Standard SQL is way more powerful than legacy.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard: promote to answer? ;-)

Comment: Added as an answer with some links (I'm not sure if there are other causes of the disparity, though).

Comment: Just a heads up, we are working through everyone's answers, and will pick one soon. Thanks for all the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're including product list views in your query.
As described in https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719 you need to make sure, that no product has `isImpression = TRUE` because that would mean it is a product list view.

This query sums all sessions which contain any action_type='2' for which all isProduct are null or false:

```
SELECT
  SUM(totals.visits) AS sessions
FROM
  `project.123456789.ga_sessions_20180101` AS t
WHERE
  (
  SELECT
    LOGICAL_OR(h.ecommerceaction.action_type='2')
  FROM
    t.hits AS h
  WHERE
    (SELECT LOGICAL_AND(isimpression IS NULL OR isimpression = FALSE) FROM h.product))
```

For legacySQL you can adapt the example in the documentation.

Comment: This answer gets the closest to the interface. I believe this is because the totals columns are precalculated metrics that the UI actually accesses. I don't understand why the values are different from doing manual sums, but that is a different question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the issue is that `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` is approximate when using legacy SQL, [as noted in the migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#advantages_of_standard_sql), so the counts are not accurate. Either use [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) instead (preferred) or use [`EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#exact_count_distinct) with legacy SQL.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the fact that `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` is approximate when using legacy SQL, there could be sessions in which there are only non-interactive hits, which will not be counted as sessions in the Google Analytics UI but they are counted by both `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` and `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(...)` because in your query they count visit id's.

Using `SUM(totals.visits)` you should get the same result as in the UI because SUM does not take into account NULL values of totals.visits (corresponding to sessions in which there are only non-interactive hits).